# How to increase database size from 2MB to 6MB in free 000webhost

Tags: database, cpanel

I am using free hosting of 000Webhost. The problem is that my database size is 5.1MB and the maximum allowed size is 2MB. Now when I am uploading my database on server, I get this error:

"No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration. See FAQ 1.16"

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a free hosting package. If that limit is setup on the server the most probably you won't be allowed to change it by yourself. You have to contact the support guys from 000webhost and ask them how to proceed. Or get a decent webhosting package or upgrade your current one.